# Emacs ESS: pipe output from R REPL into buffer

Tags: r, emacs, pipe, read-eval-print-loop, ess

I want to have the ability to execute statements on R's REPL with the option to pipe it to a buffer so I can quickly refer back to it later.

To run a shell command and output to `*shell command buffer*` I can use `M-!` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590872/pipe-emacs-shell-output-to-a-new-buffer). What would the equivalent be for R's REPL without resorting to `write.csv()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ess-command` from `ess-inf` to redirect the output to another buffer.  An example could look like the following,

```
(defun redirect-ess-output (command &optional buffer process)
  (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer "Command: ")))
  (let ((buff (get-buffer-create (or buffer "*r-output*")))
        ;; 'ess-get-process' defaults to process local to current
        ;; buffer, so to call from anywhere default to "R"
        (proc (ess-get-process (or process "R"))))
    ;; send a trailing newline to process
    (unless (string-match-p "\n$" command)
      (setq command (concat command "\n")))
    (ess-command command buff 'sleep nil nil proc)
    (with-current-buffer buff
      ;; process stuff
      (pop-to-buffer buff))))
```